# Using in code-behind a custom `Style`, declared in xaml, throws run-time error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, datatemplate

I declare a style in xaml that I need to use and apply to a user control in code behind and when I use the same style twice the following error throws:

> Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old
>   parent before it is attached to a new one.

What am I doing wrong? I need to create multiple controls of the same user-control-type in code behind and apply one and the same `Style` to it.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart"
    x:Class="MyChartControl.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="655" Width="1020">

<Window.Resources>

   <Style x:Key="SciChartSurfaceStyle" TargetType="{x:Type s:SciChartSurface}">

        <Setter Property="XAxis">
            <Setter.Value>
                <s:DateTimeAxis Visibility="Visible"
                                TextFormatting="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                SubDayTextFormatting="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"
                                GrowBy="0.02, 0.02"/>      
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="YAxis">
            <Setter.Value>
                <s:NumericAxis  AxisAlignment="Right"
                                Visibility="Visible" 
                                TextFormatting="{Binding YAxisFormatting}" 
                                GrowBy="0.02, 0.02" 
                                AutoRange="Always"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ChartModifier">
            <Setter.Value>
                <s:ModifierGroup>

                    <s:RubberBandXyZoomModifier IsAnimated = "False" IsXAxisOnly = "True" ExecuteOn = "MouseRightButton"/>
                    <s:ZoomPanModifier XyDirection="XYDirection" ClipModeX = "ClipAtExtents" ExecuteOn ="MouseLeftButton" />
                    <s:MouseWheelZoomModifier XyDirection = "XYDirection"/>
                    <s:ZoomExtentsModifier IsAnimated = "False" ExecuteOn = "MouseDoubleClick" />
                    <s:XAxisDragModifier  DragMode = "Scale"/>
                    <s:CursorModifier SourceMode="AllSeries"  UseInterpolation="True"/>
                    <s:LegendModifier ShowLegend="True" LegendPlacement ="Inside" GetLegendDataFor="AllSeries" Margin="10"/>

                     <!--<s:SeriesSelectionModifier ReceiveHandledEvents="True">
                            <s:SeriesSelectionModifier.SelectedSeriesStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="s:BaseRenderableSeries">
                                    <Setter Property="SeriesColor" Value="White"/>
                                    <Setter Property="PointMarkerTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <s:EllipsePointMarker Fill="#FF00DC" Stroke="White" Width="7" Height="7"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </s:SeriesSelectionModifier.SelectedSeriesStyle>
                        </s:SeriesSelectionModifier>-->


                </s:ModifierGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
        <TextBlock Text="Dataseries Type:" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_ChooseSeriesType" MinWidth="140" Margin="5,3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Theme:" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_ChooseTheme" MinWidth="140" Margin="5,3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>


        <dxdo:LayoutGroup Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LayoutGroup" Orientation="Vertical">

            <!--<dxdo:LayoutPanel Name="Panel1">
                <s:SciChartSurface Name="Surface1" Style="{StaticResource SciChartSurfaceStyle}"></s:SciChartSurface>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>-->




    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>



    </Grid>
```

And the code-behind method that retrieves the `style` and applies it:

```
private void TestSomeStuff()
    {
        var style = this.TryFindResource("SciChartSurfaceStyle") as Style;
        var sciChartSurface1 = new SciChartSurface() {Style = style};
        var panel1 = new LayoutPanel(){Content=sciChartSurface1};

        var style2 = this.TryFindResource("SciChartSurfaceStyle") as Style;
        var sciChartSurface2 = new SciChartSurface() {Style = style2};
        var panel2 = new LayoutPanel() {Content = sciChartSurface2};
        LayoutGroup.Add(panel1);
        LayoutGroup.Add(panel2);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Adding `panel1` to `LayoutGroup` works just fine but the run-time error occurs as soon as I attempt to add `panel2`. Also, as long as do not inject `style` into a new instance of `SciChartSurface` it works just fine. The error pops up as soon as I inject the style into both new surfaces.

Comment: In which line you have the exception and is there any inner exception?

Comment: It does not show (no inner exception message) and the error is thrown after the last line in code behind is executed, the error must be referring to the tree on the rendering side.

Comment: Try to check whether `sciChartSurface1` and `sciChartSurface2` or `panel1` and `panel2` doesn't have same value assigned to `Name` property. Sometimes can be problem in this.

Comment: Did you try to replace DexExpress and abtsoftware controls with similar standard ones? Do you get the same exception yet?

Comment: @Il Vic, I would not be using DevExpress or SciChart if standard controls offered similar features, so I do need to work with those libraries though I do not believe those libraries to be the issue.

Comment: @user2250152, good idea, I tried it but did not make a difference. I believe I may declare the style in xaml in a wrong way or how I access the style and inject it into a new `surface` or `panel`.

Comment: Hi Matt. I guess that your using DevExpress or SciChart controls since you need them. What I meant is trying to replace those controls with standard ones, so if you get no exception, then the issue regards the no-standard controls.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set Style in code behind directly:

```
var style = this.TryFindResource("SciChartSurfaceStyle") as Style;
var sciChartSurface1 = new SciChartSurface() {Style = style};
```

but with `SetValue` method:

```
var style = this.TryFindResource("SciChartSurfaceStyle") as Style;
var sciChartSurface1 = new SciChartSurface();
sciChartSurface1.SetValue(StyleProperty, style);
```